# Extract GOP structure of a given video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get something like: IBBBPBBBPBBBIBBBPBBBPBBBI...

In example below, this video is of M=4,N=12 type, i.e distance between two I-frames is 12 and there are the most 3 adjacent B-frames. Since
 "ffmpeg -i >input<" and "mediainfo >input<" sometimes don't show this information, I'm wondering is there some alternative?